# Xamarin.Forms: convert an ImageSource an Image Byte array

Tags: arrays, image, xamarin.forms, bitmap, imagesource

I work on a **Xamarin.Forms app** where I've implemented a signature control with the [Syncfusion SfSignaturePad](https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/signaturepad/overview)

I would like to send the signature image to an API.

For this, I've converted the `ImageSource` of the related signature to a `byte array` like this:

```
SfSignaturePad signaturePad;

public byte[] SignaturePadImage { get; set; }

private void BtnConvert_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    signaturePad.Save();
    if (signaturePad.ImageSource != null)
    {
        StreamImageSource streamImageSource = (StreamImageSource)signaturePad.ImageSource;
        System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken =
            System.Threading.CancellationToken.None;
        Task<Stream> task = streamImageSource.Stream(cancellationToken);
        Stream stream = task.Result;

        // store bytes
        SignaturePadImage = new byte[stream.Length];
        stream.Read(SignaturePadImage, 0, SignaturePadImage.Length);
    }
}
```

This allows me to set the `byte array` as `Source` of an `Image` to display the corresponding image.

But when I send the `byte array` to the API, the image format is not recognized, as it based on a `Xamarin.Forms.ImageSource`.

So I would like to "convert" my `ImageSource` to a **formated image** (as .PNG, .BMP, ...) before to recover the `byte array`.

***What should be the better approach to achieve this?***

Comment: I'd suggest using the Xamarin SignaturePad control instead.  The SF control is not very flexible

Comment: This [one](https://github.com/xamarin/SignaturePad)? Is it still "functional" after 3 years?

Comment: yes, I just used it in a project and it worked great

Answer (score 1):

According to jason's opinion, I use **Xamarin.Controls.SignaturePad**, and I get image by `signatureView.GetImageStreamAsync(SignatureImageFormat.Png)` and convert to byte[].

Firstly, install **Xamarin.Controls.SignaturePad.Forms**

Then using SignaturePadView, please following code.

```
<ContentPage
x:Class="FormsSample.images.Page1"
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:SignaturePad.Forms;assembly=SignaturePad.Forms">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout x:Name="imagestack">
       
        <Button
            x:Name="btn2"
            Clicked="btn2_Clicked"
            Text="get image from signturePadview" />
        <controls:SignaturePadView
            x:Name="signatureView"
            BackgroundColor="Gray"
            StrokeColor="White"
            StrokeWidth="3" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

```
private async void btn2_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var image = new Xamarin.Forms.Image();
        byte[] buffer;
        using (Stream bitmap = await signatureView.GetImageStreamAsync(SignatureImageFormat.Png))
        {
            if(bitmap!=null)
            {
                long length = bitmap.Length;
                buffer = new byte[length];
                bitmap.Read(buffer, 0, (int)length);

                var stream1 = new MemoryStream(buffer);
                image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream1);

                image.WidthRequest = 50;
                image.HeightRequest = 50;
                imagestack.Children.Add(image);
            }
           
        }
    }
```

I convert signatureView image source to byte[], then display on the Xamarin.Forms Image, the **byte[] buffer** is the Image Byte array, that you want to get.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your suggestions.

Finally, I've implemented another solution, as `FFImageLoading` is already used on this project.

For this, I use `CachedImage` instead of `Image`:

```
<ffimageloading:CachedImage x:Name="signatureImg"
        Source="{Binding Source={x:Reference SignatureView}, Path=SignaturePadImageSource, Mode=TwoWay}"
        IsVisible="{Binding Source={x:Reference SignatureView}, Path=IsSignatureMode, Converter={StaticResource InverseBoolConverter}}"
        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        BackgroundColor="{Binding Source={x:Reference SignatureView}, Path=BackColor}" />
```

Then subscribe to the `Success` event from `CachedImage` in the constructor of my control:

```
public CustomSignature()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    signaturePad = sfSignaturePad;
    IsSignatureMode = true;
    signatureImg.Success += SignatureImg_Success;
}
```

Then I can use the `GetImageAsPngAsync()` method from **FFImageLoading**.

```
private async void SignatureImg_Success(object sender, CachedImageEvents.SuccessEventArgs e)
{
    SignaturePadImage2Bytes = await signatureImg.GetImageAsPngAsync((int)signatureImg.Width, (int)signatureImg.Height);
}
```

I can share the PNG bytes array like this.